# Calendar.js Want to display 'February 2014' not as '02 2014' (%m %Y),

Tags: javascript, calendar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("trigger_filters_created_at_from").disabled = false;
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "year_month",
        ifFormat : "%m %Y",  //displays date as 02 2014, But i want it as 'February 2014'
        daFormat : "%m %Y", //MM yy
        button : "trigger_filters_created_at_from",
        showsTime : true
    });
</script>
```

Hi, As i Mentioned in  the comments like i want to display the value as 'February 2014' or as '02 2014', Can you guys give me the proper expression to achieve this.

Comment: I think this is the calendar you're using - here's the documentation for the format parameters - http://www.dni.ru/js/doc/html/reference.html#node_sec_5.3.5 - I think you want %B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("trigger_filters_created_at_from").disabled = false;
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField : "year_month",
        ifFormat : "%B %Y",  //displays date as 02 2014, But i want it as 'February 2014'
        daFormat : "%m %Y", //MM yy
        button : "trigger_filters_created_at_from",
        showsTime : true
    });
</script>
```

Use %B instead of %m

More info http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/#sec34

Comment: Glad to know it helped